# Object Object Error in using JSON in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, json, object

I have a problem in returning a value in JSON in vb .net. Please see below codes for your reference.

This is my javascript code.

```
    //beging ajax       
$.ajax({    
    type: "POST",    
    url: "../webservices/addpage.asmx/getValue",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",      
    success: function(msg){
        alert(msg);
    },
    error: function(msg){
        alert("Error "+ msg);
    }
});

    //end ajax
```

This is my json code when I clicked the submit button:

```
<%@ WebService Language="VB" Class="addpage" %>

Imports System
imports System.Collections.Generic 
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols
Imports System.Web.Script.Services
Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization
Imports System.Web.Hosting
Imports System.Web.HttpContext
Imports System.IO

<WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
<WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<ScriptService()> _
Public Class addpage
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

    <WebMethod()> _
    Public Function getValue() As String
        Return "Invalid"
    End Function

End Class
```

My scenario is that, when i pressed the button then it should alert the value returned by the getValue function but in my case it always alert an error of [Object Object].

I am new in vb.net, please advise me on how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [jquery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), the result of a $.ajax query is a jQuery XMLHttpRequest (jqXHR) object, which is a superset of XMLHttpRequest.

This means that you should be able to rewrite your success method as:

```
success: function(msg){
    alert(msg.responseText);
},
```

Comment: Hi competent_tech, thank you for your response but when I followed your suggestion "alert(msg.responseText)" it now say's "undefined". Please help me with this one, thank you in advance